# ExoPlayer how to show loading first frame during loading of video

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

I'm having an API serving the video URI and a (preloaded!) first frame URI. How can I initialize the ExoPlayer with the already available first frame?

```
@Singleton
class MediaPlayer @Inject constructor(private val context: Context) {

    companion object {
        var exoPlayer: SimpleExoPlayer? = null
        var pauseItem = false
    }

    fun initializeExoplayer(uri: Uri): SimpleExoPlayer {
        if (exoPlayer != null) {
            resetPlayer()
        }

        val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector()

        trackSelector.setParameters(
            DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder()
                .setForceLowestBitrate(true)
                .setMaxAudioBitrate(128_000)
        )

        exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector)

        val mediaSource = createMediaSource(uri)
        val loopingSource = LoopingMediaSource(mediaSource)

        exoPlayer?.prepare(loopingSource)
        exoPlayer?.volume = 1f

        return exoPlayer!!
    }

    fun resetPlayer() {
        exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = false
        exoPlayer?.stop()
        exoPlayer?.release()
        exoPlayer = null
    }

    private fun createMediaSource(uri: Uri): MediaSource {
        val userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(context, "ExoPlayerIntro")
        val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, userAgent)

        val mediaSource =
            ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory, DefaultExtractorsFactory())
                .createMediaSource(uri)

        return Objects.requireNonNull(mediaSource, "MediaSource cannot be null")
    }
}
```

I've also asked the Google Team:
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/8139

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any solution to this problem either. However, it can be solved by using an additional ImageView.
I solved the same problem in MediaPlayer by overlapping an ImageView over the Video's SurfaceView.

1. Load the first frame of the video in the ImageView. Ensure that the size and position of the ImageView hides the Video/SurfaceView.
2. As soon as the video's first frame is rendered, hide the ImageView.

Step 2 can be achieved by :

**MediaPlayer** :

```
val onInfoListener = object : MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener {
    override fun onInfo(mp: MediaPlayer?, what: Int, extra: Int): Boolean {
        if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START) {
            imageView.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        return false
    }
}
mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(onInfoListener)
```

**ExoPlayer** :
You can use onRenderedFirstFrame callback in the VideoListener, and hide the ImageView in a similar way.

Documentation :

```
default void onRenderedFirstFrame()
```

Called when a frame is rendered for the first time since setting the surface, or since the renderer was reset, or since the stream being rendered was changed.

https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/video/VideoListener.html#onRenderedFirstFrame--

Answer (score 0):

I using a **imageView** overlay video and using Glide load first frame at 1s

```
Glide.with(context).asBitmap()
                    .load(videoUri)
                    .apply(new RequestOptions().frame(1000))
                    .into(imageView);
```